# execute JavaExec task using gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've created simple `build.gradle.kts` file

```
group  = "com.lapots.breed"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

plugins { java }

java { sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 }

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {}

task<JavaExec>("execute") {
    main = "com.lapots.breed.Application"
    classpath = java.sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
}
```

In `src/main/java/com.lapots.breed` I created `Application` class with main method

```
package com.lapots.breed;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

But when I try to execute `execute` tasks it fails with the error that task doesn't exist. Also when I list all the available tasks using `gradlew tasks` it doesn't show `execute` task at all.

What is the problem?

Comment: Tasks without a `group` set don't show up in `./gradlew tasks`, you can use `./gradlew tasks --all` to list them all.

Answer (score 17):

The following build script should work (Gradle `4.10.2`, Kotlin DSL `1.0-rc-6`):

```gradle
group = "com.lapots.breed"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

plugins {
    java
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task("execute", JavaExec::class) {
    main = "com.lapots.breed.Application"
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
}
```

According the not-listed task - from certain version, Gradle doesn't show custom tasks which don't have assigned [AbstractTask.group](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/b4d8d5d170bb4ba516e88d7fe5647e2323d791dd/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/AbstractTask.java#L568). You can either list them via `gradle tasks --all`, or set the `group` property on the given task(s), e.g.:

```gradle
task("execute", JavaExec::class) {
    group = "myCustomTasks"
    main = "com.lapots.breed.Application"
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
}
```