# Gradle application plugin with kotlin DSL with multiple main classes

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, groovy, dsl

I am have a java application that has multiple main classes, the build.gradle is written in kotlin and named build.gradle.kts

It is failing with error Build failed with an exception

Script compilation errors:

Line 50: task(runSimple, dependsOn: "classes", type: JavaExec) {

Expecting ')'

I can solve the problem by using build.gradle as shown in [Gradle application plugin with multiple main classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937169/gradle-application-plugin-with-multiple-main-classes)

but team want to stay with kotlin

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task(runSimple, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) { 
   main = 'com.mrhaki.java.Simple'
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
   args 'mrhaki'
   systemProperty 'simple.message', 'Hello '
}
```

is the code when build.gradle is used and it does work,

but

```
plugins {
  java 
  application
}

task(runSimple, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
   main = 'com.mrhaki.java.Simple'
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
   args 'mrhaki'
   systemProperty 'simple.message', 'Hello '
}
```

does not work

It should be able to run the class com.mrhaki.java.Simple but does not

I guess the kotlin translation is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found [execute JavaExec task using gradle kotlin dsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810254/execute-javaexec-task-using-gradle-kotlin-dsl) and that helped me. It can be run from command line as 
**./gradlew runSimple --debug-jvm**

```
group = "com.lapots.breed"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

plugins {
    java
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task("runSimple", JavaExec::class) {
    main = "com.mrhaki.java.Simple"
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344114/gradle-change-default-port-from-5005

Comment: With gradle 8.2 I had to use: 
task("runSimple", JavaExec::class) {
    mainClass.set("com.mrhaki.java.Simple")
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
}

Answer (score 2):

if you want debug also then modify task as follows and run with ***./gradlew runSimple*** , taken from [gradle: change default port from 5005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344114/gradle-change-default-port-from-5005)

> no --debug-jvm needed

```
task("runSimple", JavaExec::class) {
    main = "com.mrhaki.java.Simple"
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath

jvmArgs= listOf( "-Xdebug", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y")
    }
```